# Is it ok to use many socket.io events?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

In socket.io for node.js you create events using:
socket.on('my event', function (data) {...});

In my case I may need to use a lot of different events (close to a 100), so I'm wondering if each of these events creates a separate listener for each client socket and would take more resources than just having a single event that receives an object that contains and identifier on which I can use switch for the events I require. Which option would be better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They will not create new sockets for each event, you can send as many events as you want. When the socket packet goes down the wire, the event name is just a text property.

If you use your own event-name system, then you will probably just be rewriting the one already there.

Answer (score 0):

There should not be an issue having over 100 events for a socket.io connection.

Each even does **not** create a new connection, so there should not be a "too many connections" issue.